# Command substation does not work inside a curl

Tags: json, unix, curl

I am using the following curl command to post the following json data.

```
curl -d 'json_data={"operation":"core/update","comment":"Synchronization from blah...","class":"Incident","key":{"ref":"I-000060"},"fields":{"public_log":"$(pwd)"}}' 'http://172.27.220.46/itop/webservices/rest.php?version=1.1&auth_user=admin1123&auth_pwd=xxxxx'
```

I am using a command substitution in the form $(pwd), however this is not recognised, and the curl posts it in the explicit form $(pwd) instead of "root".

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the whole JSON string is surrounded by the single quote `'` which stops Bash for expanding anything:

```
  ~/temp> export MY_VAR=Hello
  ~/temp>
  ~/temp> echo "$MY_VAR"
  Hello
  ~/temp> echo '$MY_VAR'
  $MY_VAR
```

You'll have to replace the single quote with double quotes and escape the other double quotes:

```
 curl -d "json_data={\"operation\":...
```

Reference:

- [GNU Bash Reference - Single Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)
- [GNU Bash Reference - Double Quotes](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)